# Mongoid search like with integer

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want use mongoid search like query with integer column.

I know use mongodb can use below command to query

`db.test.find({ $where: "/^123.*/.test(this.example)" })`

How write it with mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

You know you can use all the usual MongoDB query operators with Mongoid's `where` so:

```
Test.where(:$where => '/^123/.test(this.example)')
```

If you look at the `Mongoid::Criteria` that that `where` gives you, you'll see something like this:

```
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$where"=>"/^123/.test(this.example)"}
  options:  {}
  class:    Test
  embedded: false>
```

and there's the underlying MongoDB query in `selector`.

BTW, that `.*` didn't do anything useful in your regex so I took it out.